# Como "limpar" variáveis estáticas?

Tags: c++, recursão, variáveis

Em C++ as variáveis estáticas são muito importantes. Vamos supor que eu queira fazer um fatorial que usa recursão.

```
unsigned long long int RecursionFatorial(unsigned int fator)
{
    static long long int FatReturn;
    if(fator == 0)
    {
        unsigned long long int FatReturn_ = FatReturn;
        FatReturn = 0;
        return FatReturn_;
    }
    else
    {
        if(FatReturn == 0) FatReturn = 1;
        FatReturn *= fator;
        RecursionFatorial(fator - 1);
    }
}
```

O código roda e dá o resultado esperado, mas o código fica maior: é preciso criar novas variáveis (não estáticas) para poder resetar as variáveis que são estáticas, checar se a nova é zero para poder alterar o valor (primeira chamada) e causa ocupação de memória desnecessária. Como devemos fazer a boa utilização de variáveis estáticas e depois limpá-las?

Comment: Na verdade, este uso que você fez de variáveis estáticas não é recomendado. Se duas threads chamarem a sua função em paralelo o resultado não vai ser definido.

Comment: Uma curiosidade interessante é que a razão que FORTRAN 77 não permitia recursão é precisamente porque as variáveis locais e o valor de retorno das funções era armazenadas em locais estáticos ao invés de usarem a pilha.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma variável estática (declarada dentro de um método) irá manter seu valor entre chamadas sucessivas. Se você não deseja manter o valor entre chamadas sucessivas, por que não simplesmente usar variáveis locais (não estáticas)? O fatorial recursivo poderia ser implementado de forma mais simples (inclusive sem variáveis locais ou estáticas):

```
unsigned long long int RecursionFatorial(unsigned int fator)
{    
    if(fator == 0)
    {
        return 1;        
    }
    else
    {
        return fator * RecursionFatorial(fator - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Se você precisa disso, tem algo errado no seu design.

Variáveis estáticas em funções devem ser usadas para armazenar um estado **global**, não um estado momentâneo da operação.

Em primeiro lugar, você não precisa de um estado para uma função recursiva. Você pode usar o valor de retorno diretamente:

```
unsigned long long fatorial(unsigned fator) {
    return fator == 0 ? 1 : fator * fatorial(fator-1);
}
```

Outra forma comum é usar um parâmetro para guardar o estado:

```
unsigned long long fatorial(unsigned fator, unsigned long long resultado = 1) {
    return fator == 0 ? resultado : fatorial(fator - 1, resultado * fator);
}
```

Mas se você insiste em ter um estado, você pode usar um objeto. Afinal objetos foram feitos para terem estados:

```
struct Fatorial {
    unsigned long long resultado ;
    Fatorial() : resultado (1) {}
    unsigned long long calc(unsigned fator) {
        if (fator > 0) {
            resultado *= fator;
            calc(fator-1);
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}

Fatorial().calc(4) // 24
```

Note que está uma bagunça e é de longe o ideal para uma recursão.

Agora respondendo a pergunta de fato:

```
unsigned long long fatorial(unsigned fator, bool reset=true)
{
    static unsigned long long resultado;
    if (reset) resultado = 1;
    if (fator > 0) {
        resultado *= fator;
        fatorial(fator-1, false);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: No comecinho: "Vamos supor que eu queira fazer um fatorial[...]"

Comment: Não entendi.  eu supus que você estava a fazer algo similar a um fatorial. O que disse em minha resposta se aplica.

Comment: Sim, ela está correta. Você disse sobre o design, mas é só um exemplo ;)

Comment: Sim. Mas se você está a usar variáveis estáticas para o estado de funções recursivas, *sejam ou não fatorial*, tem algo errado com o seu design. Considere uma alternativa.